# I have a text field, which will accept only the NEXT TO NEXT ALPHANUMERIC that is single alphabet next is single numeric FOR EXAMPLE:- s3f4G5A2s3

Tags: jquery, regex, onkeypress

javascript:

script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"

$(document).ready(function()

{

$(function(){

$('#custom_Expression').keypress(function(e){

var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);

```
if(!txt.match(/^([a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}$/g))

            {
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

input type="text" id="custom_expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow single alphabet followed by single numeric, one or more times won't need `+` after `[A-Za-z]` and `[0-9]`. Most cases , anchors are necessary while validating  strings. `^` asserts that we are at the start, `$` asserts that we are at the end.

```
var re= /^([a-zA-Z][0-9])+$/g;
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

OR

```
var re= /^([a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}$/g;
```

repitition quantifier `{3}` repeats the previous token exactly 3 times.

Comment: how to restrict wrong input to not get type in textbox

Comment: thank you for ur response sir;exactly i need is onkeypress itself restrict wrong format..

Comment: how to restrict to type wrong input by using onkeypress event

Comment: sorry, i don't know about onepress event. Seems like my answer didn't help you, so i'll delete it.

Comment: your expression is correct but i need to restrict wrong input on keypress

Comment: wait for some more time. Someone will help you.

Comment: the following code regular expression not work in keypress event but it works without key press event :                             $(function(){
    $('#t').keypress(function(e){
        var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);
        if(!txt.match(/^([a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}$/g))
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});